# How to create conda env using exported yaml from aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, anaconda

I have exported `environment.yml` from one of the aws servers. I want to create a conda env in my local system with this yml file. But I am getting errors like below:

```
ResolvePackageNotFound: 
 - openmpi==4.0.2=hb1b8bf9_1
 - xz==5.2.4=h14c3975_4
 - unicodecsv==0.14.1=py36_0
 - cytoolz==0.10.1=py36h7b6447c_0
 - kiwisolver==1.1.0=py36he6710b0_0
 - etc...
```

Is there any way I can bypass these errors and install whatever are available? I have searched in conda env create documentation could not find options to do that.

Comment: What is the local platform (e.g., **win-64**, **osx-64**)? By default, envs exports are not cross-platform. However, one can loosen the specificity of the export by using `conda env export --no-builds` flag, which removes the build ids (often platform specific).  Or even further, use `conda env export --from-history`, which will only use the explicit specifications the user has imposed on the env.

Answer (score 0):

To create an environment from an environment file use:

```
conda env create -f environment.yaml
```

This will create a new environment with the same name listed in environment.yaml

If you have created the environment this way and you get the error, the environment was likely exported on a different platform that the target machine and some modules can not be installed. You could try to modify the .yaml file to **exclude** the 'problematic' packets and then make an extensive text on your code to see if everything works fine.